# Add objects differences to the "right" position

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I've got an difference object from my server and need to merge it into a local representation.
So I need a way to add the part of the object which is currently undefined inside the original representation.

Example:

```
// The serverresponse
{
  "PRIVATE": {
      "SCREENS": {
          "WORKSPACE": {
              "POSTS": {
                  "1363391397125": {
                      "TGT": "1363390641817",
                      "ACN": "position",
                      "TO": [
                          57.1875,
                          69.21182266009852
                      ]
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
}

// This part is similar to my local representation
{
  "PRIVATE": {
      "SCREENS": {
          "WORKSPACE": {
              "POSTS": {}
           }
       }
}


// So I want to insert this part of the given data at same position inside the local data
{
  "1363391397125": {
                    "TGT": "1363390641817",
                    "ACN": "position",
                    "TO": [
                          57.1875,
                          69.21182266009852
                      ]
                  }
}
```

There are a lot of different parts to insert so I'm looking explicit for an alternative to iterate for each case I will have.

Comment: So you want to merge these two objects, but only putting a property into the original if it was previously undefined in the original?  If the property already exists in the original, just leave it alone even if a different value comes in the server response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing you added the jQuery tag you could use jQuery's [**extend()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) method, similar to the below:

```
// The serverresponse
var x = {
    "PRIVATE": {
        "SCREENS": {
            "WORKSPACE": {
                "POSTS": {
                    "1363391397125": {
                        "TGT": "1363390641817",
                            "ACN": "position",
                            "TO": [
                        57.1875,
                        69.21182266009852]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

// This part is similar to my local representation
var y = {
    "PRIVATE": {
        "SCREENS": {
            "WORKSPACE": {
                "POSTS": {}
            }
        }
    }
};

// merges x into y
$.extend(y, x); 

// use $.extend(x, y); if you intended it to be the other way around.
```

---

DEMO - using `$.extend()` to merge objects.

---

Comment: I don't think `$.extend()` quite does what the OP wants (though their question is not crystal clear).  I've asked in a comment above for clarification on the OP's question, but I think they only want to put things into the original object from the new object if the original did not already have that property.

Comment: @jfriend00: +1. If there is more checks involved and only some parts should be merged then `$.extend()` would be to generic and I would have to re-consider my answer indeed.

Comment: @François Wahl THX Exactly what I needed. Didnt worked with extend for a very long time.

Comment: @Bernhard: `extend()` is very generic and if you would already have data inside `POSTS` for example on the `y` object you it would be lost and overwritten with the `POSTS` from the `x` object. To preserve existing data you would have to merge each sub-object separately similar to: `$.extend(y.PRIVATE.SCREENS.WORKSPACE.POSTS, x.PRIVATE.SCREENS.WORKSPACE.POSTS);`  I'm sure you could write a re-cursive method which iterates through each object and child-object and uses `extend()` on each one.

Comment: right and also unset parts is required so I thing a "forced" extend would be finally what I need. But extend is the right point to work from I think

Comment: @François Wahl the response should exactly do that. So it's ensured that I can remove items also.

Comment: @Bernhard: If you do need to preserve data (I just double-checked documentation) using `true` will merge recursively. `$.extend(true, y, x);` That will preserve any existing data on the target object. So no need to write your own recursive method as I originally thought.

Comment: @François Wahl thank you soo much for your help. So my night is going a little bit shorter ;-)